# Generics compile errors in Kotlin 1.4 vs 1.3

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin1.4

I have the following code ([here is the link](https://pl.kotl.in/B1ul4rhIP) to the Kotlin Playground):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

sealed class CallResult<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : CallResult<T>()
    data class Failure(val error: String) : CallResult<Nothing>()
}

public data class Response<T>(val body: T?)

suspend fun <T : Any> f1(lambda: suspend () -> Response<T>): T = when(val result = f3(lambda())) {
    is CallResult.Success -> result.data
    is CallResult.Failure -> throw Exception()
}

fun <T : Any> f3(response: Response<T>): CallResult<T> {
    val body = response.body
    if (body != null) {
        return CallResult.Success(body)
    } else {
        return CallResult.Failure("error")
    }
}

fun f4(): Response<Any> {
    return Response(Any())
}

fun main() {

    GlobalScope.launch {
        f1 { f4() }
    }

    print("done!")

}
```

This code compiles and **works fine in Kotlin 1.3.72** but gives the following compile errors in **Kotlin 1.4.30**, saying that `f4()` cannot be called in `f1`:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Response<Any> but Response<Unit> was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but Unit was expected
```

Fun fact: this happens only when it is the last call in a lambda (making it a return result), otherwise it compiles also in 1.4:

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
        f1 { f4() }
        print("test") // adding this makes it compile in 1.4
    }
```

Can someone explain me what changes in **1.4** caused this to start failing to compile?

Comment: Probably the [New more powerful type inference algorithm](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#new-more-powerful-type-inference-algorithm).

Comment: @GeorgeLeung I guess so, I have opened a ticket to help the guys fix it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44889